# PushMessage containing a filepath hyperlink

Tags: pyqgis, hyperlink

I am trying to create a pushbbar message which contains a hyperlink to a local filepath.

However the following code does not create the desired result (layer is exported, click on pushmessages hides pushmessage, but explorer does not show).

```
QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer_data, path_exportdata, "utf-8", layer_data.crs(), 'xlsx')
message=f'Layer was exported to <a href="file://{path_exportdata}">{path_exportdata}</a>'
iface.messageBar().pushMessage("Done", message , level=Qgis.Success, duration=20)
```

Comment: Could you share a resulting message string?

Comment: the message string ist: Layer was exported to <a href="file://C:/Users/ANONYM/OneDrive - anonym/PYGIS\\export.xlsx">C:/Users/ANONYM/OneDrive - anonym/PYGIS\\export.xlsx</a>'

Might the error be due to the diffrent / and \? how would I resolve this?

Comment: Try an additional slash at the beginning: `file:///` and maybe replace the `\\` with a `/`: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme

Comment: Did the job! tripple "/". Thanks

Comment: Nice! I posted it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless your `path_exportdata` already starts with a `/` slash, you need to add one more to the `file://` prefix. It is surprising but that's how those paths work: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme

This should work:

```
message=f'Layer was exported to <a href="file:///{path_exportdata}">{path_exportdata}</a>'
```